# Adding a hover tool tip to id's with javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't want to change the html structure in a legacy application. Just want to add javascript on top to add tooltips for a few id.

Several libraries how options that rely on specific HTML structure or integrating a full tooltip library which is difficult on a legacy application.

Something like this but without adding HTML. Just finding id's and apply what's needed for a simple black background tooltip. Like the tooltips on StackOverflow reputation page.
[image]

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var couponcodes = document.getElementsByClassName("couponcode");
    for (var i = 0; i < couponcodes.length; i++) {
        couponcodes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            var coupontooltip = this.getElementsByClassName("coupontooltip")[0];
            coupontooltip.removeAttribute("style");
        });
        couponcodes[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            var coupontooltip = this.getElementsByClassName("coupontooltip")[0];
            coupontooltip.style.display = "none";
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynetx/5qbP3/

How can I add a tooltip for an id with JS/jQuery only?

Comment: If you prefer, you can still add a tooltip using css and you won't have to change your html structure as well, refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip

Comment: While you don't want to change your HTML structure, how about if the JavaScript manipulated your HTML to allow the tooltips, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L49o80bw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a tooltip for an id with JS/jQuery without change the html structure.

```js
jQuery(function($){
     //On hover on id create tooltip element and append to that div
  $('#add_tooltip').hover(
               function () {
                 $(this).append('<div class = "coupontooltip">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>');
                  //display the tooltip with animation.
                 $(this).find('.coupontooltip').hide().fadeIn('slow');  

                 /*if in code already tooltip section is there
       $(this).find('.coupontooltip').show();
       */
               }, 
               
              //On hover out remove the tooltip. 
               function () {
                  $(this).find('.coupontooltip').remove();
                   
                  /*if in code already tooltip section is there
       $(this).find('.coupontooltip').hide();
         */
               }
            );
})
```

```css
#add_tooltip{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.coupontooltip{
    display: inherit;
    background: black;
    width: 19px;
    /* background: #C8C8C8; */
    margin-left: 83px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 59px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add_tooltip">Add Tooltip</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Add fadein? How would you add a fadeIn of the append? To me the .fadeIn('slow') does not work on append. Just want to make a simple fadein Animation of the tooltip. Adding CSS transitions (`transition: all 0.5s ease`) to stylesheet also do not work.
`$(this).append('<div class = "coupontooltip">See below what people have previously commented</div>').fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: Hi, I edit my code to enable the animation for tooltip. Please have a look.

Comment: The fadeIn animation does not seem to work, I get an uncaught type error when adding the animation part. http://tinypic.com/r/b3lke8/9 Do you know why?

Comment: Hi checked in your site it's working fine. I apply above code for #reportImage in console to check tooltip coming with animation.